# Visual Studio Code Node.js while running npm start command it give permission denied error in Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I have import the project from my windows machine to mac
i have install the required liberaries
when i run `npm start` command it give the bellow error

> shoaibanwar@Shoaibs-MacBook-Pro frontend % npm start

> temp@0.0.0 start /Users/shoaibanwar/Desktop/WebBackup/saray/frontend
> ng serve

sh: /Users/shoaibanwar/Desktop/WebBackup/saray/frontend/node_modules/.bin/ng: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! temp@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the temp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shoaibanwar/.npm/_logs/2020-08-04T08_17_17_148Z-debug.log
shoaibanwar@Shoaibs-MacBook-Pro frontend %

Answer (score 2):

check if npm version on windows and mac are same,
if not update npm, delete node_modules folder and install again,

Comment: also can you please me to fix a little error in code

Comment: post question, if I can I will try